# How to show capture video in Phonegap?

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, video-capture

i am using phoengap capture video plugin
 i have used this code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Video</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureVideo() {
    // Launch device video recording application,
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}

// Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

it is working fine.. but i want

> how to show my video image or play the video on touch select?

i did use this

```
 path = mediaFile.fullPath
   $("div").html("<img src="+path+">");
```

not showing video image. Can you help Me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@DavidC was real close, you just need to know what property of the MediaResult ob to use, fullPath. Here is a full example.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {


    document.querySelector("#takeVideo").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
        console.log("Take video");
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
    }, false);

}

function captureError(e) {
    console.log("capture error: "+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function captureSuccess(s) {
    console.log("Success");
    console.dir(s[0]);
    var v = "<video controls='controls'>";
    v += "<source src='" + s[0].fullPath + "' type='video/mp4'>";
    v += "</video>";
    console.log(v);
    document.querySelector("#videoArea").innerHTML = v;
}
```

Comment: sure - i suppose :) i blogged it too - http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/06/05/cordova-sample-capture-and-display-video

Comment: @RaymondCamden i m getting error like  "Error in Success callbackId: Capture839271896 : TypeError: console.dir is not a function"

Comment: console.dir is not a function? Weird - what platform are you using it in? You can just replace that with console.log.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a video, I guess you should use the tag video instead of img. I can't validate this right now

```
$("div").html(' <video controls="controls">
       <source src="'+path+'" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>');
```